# prostrating during high-holiday

Tags: tefilla

During high-holidays we fully prostrate during certain prayers. However, on the women's side only a few do it (whereas on the men's side, almost everyone does). Are women supposed to fully prostrate or not? My thought is that maybe for practical reasons (such as pregnancy, menstruation, or simply women's attire skirts/dress) full prostration was optional for women.

Comment: Under "Men and Women", Harav Yehoshua Pfeffer deals with your question: https://dinonline.org/2017/09/28/kneeling-and-prostration-laws-and-customs/

Comment: As I understand, it's a matter of custom. Where I used to daven before I was married, almost *all* of the women would fully prostrate, but every other place I've davened *none* of them did. And these are all communities with similar philosophies and levels of religious observance, ie the differences are not because of feminism or other similar ideas, that's just the custom in those places.